# Query MySQL 8 para registros duplicados columna contador

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-8.0

junto con saludar.
Quisiera pedir orientación para obtener el siguiente resultado con una query:

Ejemplo Query :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE datos(
  id int,
  marca varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  modelo varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  primary key(id)
);

INSERT INTO datos(id,marca,modelo) 
 VALUES(1,"ford","focus"),
(2,"ford","F150"),
(3,"mazda","3"),
(4,"mazda","6"),
(5,"ford","escape"),
(6,"toyota","aveo"),
(7,"ford","expedition"),
(8,"toyota","rav4"),
(9,"toyota","celica");

 select * from datos;
 
 drop table datos;
```

Resultado deseado : Tener una columna "contador" que según la columna marca deje solo 1 de los registros para esa marca con valor 1, si se repite en la tabla debe ser 0.

[image]

Lo idea sería no usar with ya que debo expresar todo en una view.

Agradeceré cualquier tipo de orientación, muchas gracias.!!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio para `contador`? Creo imaginarlo, pero es mejor que lo expliques en tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Sal, edite la pregunta con lo que me señalas. Según la columna marca solo dejar un registro en 1 para todas las filas que la marca es igual.

Comment: Las vistas soportan with, por qué no usarlo?

Comment: Jachguate, tenía entendido que no funcionaban juntos...si me brindas un ejemplo sería genial !!

Comment: No se si estoy entendiendo bien, pero quieres que te muestre en la columna contador 1 vez cada marca? O quieres contar las veces que se repite cada marca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes valerte de un CTE para lograr lo que buscas, por ejemplo, se me ocurre primero simplemente numerar las filas valiéndome de la función de ventana `row_number()`, haciendo particiones por marca y ordenando por ID, y luego, seleccionar de este primer CTE y utilizando un `case` dejarle un *contador* de 1 a las filas que tienen número de fila 1 y 0 a todas las demás.

Dado que es una vista la que quieres crear, puedes crear la vista Utilizando CTE (requieres mySQL 8 o superior):

```sql
create view datos_contador as 
with 
datos_numerados as (
select id, marca, modelo, row_number() over (partition by marca order by id) numfila
  from datos
)
select id, marca, modelo, case when numfila = 1 then 1 else 0 end contador
  from datos_numerados;
```

Y luego seleccionar de la vista:

```sql
select *
  from datos_contador
 order by marca, id;
```

En mis pruebas, devuelve:

| id | marca | modelo | contador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ford | focus | 1 |
| 2 | ford | F150 | 0 |
| 5 | ford | escape | 0 |
| 7 | ford | expedition | 0 |
| 3 | mazda | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | mazda | 6 | 0 |
| 6 | toyota | aveo | 1 |
| 8 | toyota | rav4 | 0 |
| 9 | toyota | celica | 0 |

He dejado un [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SiVHpASd) para que puedas probarlo en línea.

Comment: Estimado jachguate muchisimas gracias, tu respuesta es exactamente el resultado que deseaba,  :D !!!!